# Why was my answer to my own question deleted?

Tags: support, deleted-answers, specific-answer

To [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56429901), I posted this answer:

> The best I can come up with is
>
> ```
> lines = readLines("http://web.archive.org/web/20190603144739id_/http://api-ak.wunderground.com/weatherstation/ListStations.asp?selectedCountry=fr")
> lines = ifelse(validUTF8(lines), lines,
>     iconv(lines, "Windows-1252", "UTF-8"))
> XML::readHTMLTable(lines, stringsAsFactors = F)[[1]]
> ```
>
> which doesn't solve the problem in general, because what if some of the text isn't in Windows-1252, either? But I think it suffices for my case.

It was deleted (by a single diamond moderator). None of the reasons on the [help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers) seem to apply. I've admitted that it's only a partial answer, but surely it's *at least* a partial answer, and better than nothing.

Comment: To me, the text looks like a first approach that should be incorporated in the answer. What's the point of creating a self-answered question when you only have a partial answer to it? Especially when you put a bounty on it.

Comment: @BDL I created the question first and only some days later was able to produce a partial answer. You have a point that maybe it should be an edit to the question rather than an answer, though.

Comment: Maybe the moderator got confused with the wording and the question you used within the answer. Perhaps rephrasing to make it a clear answer and flagging it for moderator intervention can cause it to be undeleted.

Comment: if you haven't already, mod-flag the answer and say it was incorrectly deleted (which I agree it was). I would re-write the last part as something along the lines of "which doesn't work as a general solution if the encoding is different, but it suffices for my case" first, to make it seem less like a question.

Comment: FWIW, reading the full answer, I would probably have made the same decision. It doesn't look like this is the final answer OP was looking for, and he seems to be asking for more. Had I been OP, I would probably have appended this to my question instead as being a non-ideal workaround/solution for which I'd like to have a better one.

Comment: @GolezTrol *It doesn't look like this is the final answer OP was looking for, and he seems to be asking for more.* Thanks for the insight! I recently self-answered a question with a non-ideal solution, and the question was downvoted. Maybe this was why!

Answer (score 62, accepted):

The answer was flagged by some user.

When I reviewed the answer, I didn't "expand" the answer, but saw it as text, just like that one

[image]

It's a compact way of seeing answers: it allows to see more flagged posts at the same time. It also hides links, which I think is done on purpose to quickly check if the answer is link-only, for instance, like that one:

[image]
Your answer, in this format appears roughly like this:

> The best I can come up with is lines = readLines("http://web.archive.org/web/20190603144739id_/http://api-ak.wunderground.com/weatherstation/ListStations.asp?selectedCountry=fr") lines = ifelse(validUTF8(lines), lines, iconv(lines, "Windows-1252", "UTF-8"))
>   XML::readHTMLTable(lines, stringsAsFactors = F)[[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/beqIx.png)]
>   which doesn't solve the problem in general, because what if some of the text isn't in Windows-1252, either? But I think it suffices for my case.

What does stand out in this form? not the code, but the end:

> because what if some of the text isn't in Windows-1252, either? But I think it suffices for my case.

So an interrogation, and a conclusion with "I think". That plus the fact that it's self-answered (sometimes users add clarifications in answers, not in the question) made me delete your answer (and probably made the other user flag it in the first place)

I should have expanded it to see it fully. Sorry. Trigger happy. My bad.

Now, what you can do:

- edit it to make it more "assertive" instead of interrogative: that's an answer, you need to convince others
- next time, just flag your deleted answer with a custom flag (no need for meta yet) and if a moderator <s>tells you to get lost</s> declines your flag, then summon meta for a consensus.

Partial answers/workarounds are considered answers.

Of course, [answer undeleted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56481156/6451573).

Comment: The fact that the mod flag view doesn't show posts as they appear on the main site boggles my mind. This is a no-brainer issue to fix on that end. Didn't it just get a rework, too?

Comment: it's like this to be able to show a lot of answers on the screen. Most of the time the text is enough to decide. Sometimes you have to expand. But I don't do it all the time. Yes, there has been a rework of the UI, but they kept that part almost identical for the reasons I stated.

Comment: I don't think that's a valuable trade-off at all, personally. *Every* time I see some 'oops' answer by a mod on Meta, it's because the mod flag interface didn't show enough context.

Comment: that's because it's the only plausible excuse we have beside our incompetence :) the other being to act quickly where there are 100+ flags in the queue.

Comment: You mean to tell me Cody and Bhargav aren't hooked up to the flag queue 24/7/365 to keep the queue empty?!

Comment: well, yes, but sometimes they sleep, and that's when problems arise.

Comment: Reversing a delete is easy, if this UI saves a lot of time and now and then causes a mistake like this, it's still worth it.

Comment: This is a fair trade-off. Every now and then there are false positives, no matter what we implement. Fact remains mods are (still) humans.

Comment: @TylerH Pardon me asking, but how can you judge whether it's a valuable tradeoff if you (from what I can tell) are not a mod and don't directly see the benefits of it? Just that something is the only source of false positives doesn't mean that it's worthless...

Comment: @MaxLanghof Note the word "personally" in my comment. You can value the tradeoff however you like, personally. One doesn't need to be a mod to make a determination on the value of context in making moderation decisions. I also never said the design choice was worthless.

Comment: @TylerH But "the value of context in making moderator decisions" is only one side of the trade-off. I was asking what led you to believe that the other side (namely the saved time/convenience) is smaller in value. You're of course free to think whatever you like, I'm just trying to see if there is something I'm missing here, because I personally don't feel qualified to judge this tradeoff due to the mentioned unknown. And no, you didn't technically say it was worthless, but you said its existence is mind-boggling - there isn't much veiling there.

Comment: @MaxLanghof Well, that's *not* what you asked, of course, but I'd be happy to answer it -- in my experience, context is important, and doubly so when dealing with interpersonal matters. I also believe we should hold moderators to a very high standard in their actions, and I regularly urge moderators to click through and view the full context on flagged items before acting. It's my opinion that the number of mod flags is not so high that they need to sacrifice quality for speed. If they don't think they can handle full context at an OK rate, they should elect more moderators (in my opinion).

Comment: @TylerH Thanks, that's a very reasonable standpoint :)

Comment: @MaxLanghof As for your equation of 'worthless' with mind-boggling, that's really an apples-to-turkey conflation. First, yes, it is mind-boggling to me that code is shown in plaintext with no highlighting or contextual indication that it's code. That doesn't mean it's worthless, though. I think the design decision to minimize the viewing portion in order to allow for more items to be shown (and thus, ostensibly increase speed) *has* worth. I just think it's much *less* worth than providing the additional context/info I've described above.

Comment: @MaxLanghof Perhaps a happy medium would be keeping the view they currently have, but on hover of the post or comment item, show a modal of what the post or comment looks like with full rendering/highlighting.

Comment: Alternative data point: as a moderator, I fully agree with @Tyler. I *always* view a flagged post in full context, as it would normally appear on the site, before rendering a decision. Occasionally, I’ll reach a conclusion before clicking through, just from the summary/preview, but even then I always verify it. It takes a few seconds more per flag, but it’s more than worth it to me. It not only gives me context, but gives me a view I’m more familiar with from regular usage of the site, increasing the odds of a correct decision. Plus, it allows me to handle *other* problems, like closing the Q.

Comment: Please no hovers, though! The queue is busy enough as it is, and hovers are just awful UX anyway. Clicking through isn’t that hard, especially if you keep one hand on the keyboard to hit Control, like I do.

Comment: not saying that I always review like that. It's just that I don't always expand the post. And yes, that can lead to mistakes.

Comment: "If they don't think they can handle full context at an OK rate, they should elect more moderators (in my opinion)." Don't come here with simple and logical solutions to problems! That is not the Stack Overflow way.

Comment: you know that we handle a lot of flags. There's one mishap from time to time, it happens and it's easily corrected. So I think the system works. Most of the time (99%) we don't need to expand posts to see they're bad (check my last edit to see what I mean).