# Should "me too" posts with additional research details be considered partial answers?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, answers, help-center, me-too-answers

There have been numerous discussions over the years on the acceptability of partial answers:

| Year | Q&A | Theme |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2010 | [Should I answer the question with just a partial solution?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72392/should-i-answer-the-question-with-just-a-partial-solution) | General acceptability of posting partial *solutions* to the problem |
| 2012 | [Should I downvote partial answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118640/should-i-downvote-partial-answer) | Self-evident: whether partial answers should be considered useful |
| 2012 | [Is it okay to put partial answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/144452/is-it-okay-to-put-partial-answers) | Also self-evident: is this acceptable to post partial answers? |
| 2014 | [Is a partial answer OK?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267126/is-a-partial-answer-ok) | Also concerned with providing a partial *solution* |
| 2015 | [Partial self-answering etiquette](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250666/partial-self-answering-etiquette) | Ethical considerations of accepting partial self-answers |
| 2017 | [Best practices for partial answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/301807/best-practices-for-partial-answers) | Advice for writing acceptable partial answers |
| 2019 | [Why was my answer to my own question deleted?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/385841/11407695) | "Partial answers/workarounds are considered answers." |
| 2021 | [What's the etiquette for improving answers that only address part of a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/411553) | Guidance on how to improve partial answers |

None of the those (except for maybe the one from 2017), however, address the following part in the help center (the highlighted part) on [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer):

> Still no answer to the question, and you have the same problem? Help us find a solution by researching the problem, then **contribute the results of your research and anything additional you’ve tried as a partial answer**. That way, even if we can’t figure it out, the next person has more to go on. You can also vote up the question or set a bounty on it so the question gets more attention.

This part seems to be in direct contradiction as to what is considered to be a partial answer as per community consensus (if you examine posts listed above, the general idea is that it is ok to post partial answers as long as they actually *solve* a part of the original problem).

This clause creates a loophole that allows "answers" that would be better off as comments, edits to the question, or potential new questions that could be used as duplicate targets if answered to be posted in a forum-like manner as a "me too" response. This also makes NAA flagging such responses, *by the letter of the law*, incorrect too.

The concern is not theoretical. It is already used (see [relevant SOCVR discussion](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/53053161#53053161)) to justify contesting the removal of such content. Please note that I am not saying that the information provided by such responses is not valuable, just that they are using the wrong medium and thus should not be officially endorsed.

This discussion has been brought up at least once before in 2016 as a clarification request that lead nowhere (given the discussion there, I accept the possibility of duplicate linking to it as the target, but I would like to make this a part of the [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) instead should the discussion be in favor of the proposal without invalidating the old Q&A):

[Why does the Help center seem to indicate "Me too!" is a valid answer?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/324340/11407695)

I propose **removing** the clause from the help center to stop confusing *both* conscientious users that do read the help center as we ask them to (and thus justifiably think this is an acceptable way to answer) and curators that find themselves in the predicament of acting against the literal interpretation of the rules.

Shamelessly piggybacking on the [famous Shog9](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/786798)'s image on what is and what is not an NAA, here is a proposed revised rendition clarifying the abovementioned ambiguity:

[image: revised NAA picture]

Comment: Also see this recent question: [What's the etiquette for improving answers that only address part of a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/411553/2985643)

Comment: @skomisa yay, thank you, I missed that one :) Will incorporate in the list a bit later

Comment: What should be done with additional research by third persons having the same problem then? Commenting or editing the question?

Comment: @Trilarion What sort of "research" are you talking about? In my experience 100% of "I'm having this problem too" "answers" are just help vampire garbage.

Comment: Usually in those cases I add comments like "Related questions: [1] [2]" under the question.

Comment: @IanKemp I mean "contribute the results of your research and anything additional you’ve tried". If it doesn't actually happen in practice, it might not be that important.

Comment: @Trilarion well yeah, last time I checked, that's what comments are for - the researcher can ask the OP to include the information in their question too. As an alternative, if the context is sufficiently different, they could post a new question and link it over with a "related" comment or, given the privilege and other answers, by voting to close as duplicate.

Comment: For me comments are for discussing existing content. New content like new research and new stuff that has been tried should eventually end up in a question somewhere. Maybe we can update that help center text to actually say where and how it should end up (not only where it shouldn't). What if the question asker does not respond anymore? Is it then okay to take over the question and enrich it with additional research?

Comment: @Trilarion well, I can't say I have a stance on where they *should* go, it may very well be editing the question too (although it probably needs a standalone discussion because there are a lot of caveats to iron out, methinks). What I do know, though, is that those additional details have no place as answers (on which, I assume, we both agree)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We've [updated the copy on this Help Center article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). I've also taken the liberty to shuffle it around a bit for clarity, and to put the more important sections first. (I do know this is a bit subjective, but the old order did seem very strange to me.)

It now clearly specifies that any 'me too'-style answer needs to fully answer at least part of the question:

> So long as you fully answer at least a part of the original question, then you can contribute the results of your research and anything additional you’ve tried.

At this point in time I'm open to making another revision only if it's especially important, ex. if I've inadvertently made the guidance much more opaque, or there's a painful typo. Or if y'all absolutely can't stand the new section order and want the old one back.

Otherwise, I'm markin' this one [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed).

Comment: What's a "full" answer? How do you "**fully**" answer "at least a part"?

Answer (score 44):

No, "me too" answers with additional details are not answers (even partial). An answer needs to actually solve at least part of the OP's problem to be considered an answer. The consensus in the community is clear on that, as far as I'm aware, and based on the discussions you've linked to.

I absolutely agree that the wording in the Help Center is misleading in this regard. I don't imagine many users read the help pages thoroughly, and even fewer who try to follow it strictly, but we shouldn't be penalizing users who do so. So, yes, the help pages could do with some editorial fixes. Something as simple as the following might be sufficient.

> Help us find a solution by researching the problem, then contribute the results of your research and anything additional you’ve tried as a partial answer, **but make sure that the answer actually solves at least part of the   question**.

I wouldn't say it's worth making an edit if the page needs to be consistent network-wide, but a quick search reveals at least one [site](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) with different wording, so it's certainly possible.

---

Also, if the page is going to be edited, the next bullet on that page **Answer the question** says,

> Any answer that gets the asker going in the right direction is helpful, [...]

which is just not true on this site, if taken literally. An answer that just says "Learn how to use a debugger." is extremely helpful advice, and definitely gets the asker going in the right direction, but such an answer would (and should) be summarily deleted, or converted to a comment at best. Similar wording as above might work here as well.

Comment: Agreed on the second part as well - having vague guidance (and "any ... that gets ..." is rather vague) is just ripe for interpretation wars and seems to be in misalignment with how community has been viewing the issue all these years.

Comment: If I have to use my time machine, that part was written before we had comments or shortly thereafter.

Comment: @Braiam That's very interesting. I didn't know there was a time when comments were not supported. The oldest mention I can find is [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756) which is just the FAQ. The earliest revision also doesn't mention it. Do you have a link to some discussion of this?

Comment: Me too! I agree all the points

Comment: I presume (and hope) nobody is going to be such a smartass to answer with only "Learn how to use a debugger." in which case, I would argue it's not even helpful, it's just belligerent. Delete those answers 100% of the time.

On the other hand, I would hope at minimum for a link to some learning resources to get them started. (Comment)

However, a full answer starting with "Learn how to use a debugger" should be followed up with a step-by-step guide and images of how to identify their issue themselves via the debugger. In which case, it should not be deleted nor a comment. It'd be partial.

Comment: @Ryan Stack Overflow does not exist to do Google searches for people who are too lazy to do them themselves. If a question is incomplete, lacks debugging information, or is otherwise unfit for this site **it should be closed**, end of story. An answer on a poor question is a waste of everyone's time.

Comment: @IanKemp Getting off topic. The subject is surrounding partial answers, not question quality. Presume, for the purpose of discussion, it's the model example of a perfect question. Where is the problem in directing the author to some online resources to assist in their learning if the problem isn't a lack of effort but a shortcoming in their knowledge. Everyone knows how to Google, not everyone knows _what_ to Google so please keep that in mind before attributing simple solutions to a lack of effort on the author's behalf.

Comment: @Ryan "Where is the problem in directing the author to some online resources" for starters, the fact that's against the rules? Answers must be **self-contained** and they must **attempt to answer the question as asked**. An answer explaining how to use a debugger would not only be off-topic, but would violate the implicit "Stack Overflow is not a discussion forum" rule. We already have a torrent of garbage rule-breaking questions, we don't need garbage rule-breaking answers too.

Comment: @IanKemp Self-contained does not mean don't include external links. Would not be off-topic as it's a question tailored to identifying their problem from the question, using their provided code. Finally, would it answer the question? **Partially**. It would in fact point the author in the right direction. When they follow the steps provided, it would allow them to identify their problem themselves and fix it. We could make it a full answer by just giving them the solution outright at the end but if you're unable to do so for whatever reason, it'd still be an acceptable partial answer without it

Comment: For example, if the author isn't even aware what's causing their issues. The above mentioned "Learn how to use a debugger" answer with the provided resources and a step-by-step on how to do so would allow the author to identify the cause of their issue, but not the solution. Hence, a **Partial Answer** as then the author can search more precisely for the solution or another user can use that answer as a basis to provide the solution themselves. This would meets @cigien's suggestion of at least solving **part of the question** to be a partial answer. Yet no such precedent is in place. Yet.

Comment: I do imagine that people read the manual, but then I also imagine lands with heroic adventures exploring dungeons and fighting dragons. Sooner or later I wake up.

Comment: @Ryan Teaching a man to fish **is still not an answer to the question as posed**. It may be the most appropriate answer, it may be the most helpful answer, it may be the objectively best answer... **but it is still not a valid answer according to this site's rules**. The simple reason is that so many garbage questions would easily be "answered" in such a way, which would encourage rep-farming on such answers **instead of having those garbage questions closed as they should be**. Again, Stack Overflow **is not a forum**, nor is it a place for teaching the absolute basics of programming.

Comment: @IanKemp Is seems to be a partial Answer. I wonder if one could post Answers instead of answering in comments. Perhaps what would make for better duplicate targets. Apart from that, there's no such thing as a Question that is too simple. Stack Overflow is for everyone, not just experienced developers. ..and what's up with the bold?

Comment: @IanKemp I just disagree wholeheartedly and don't think we'll see eye to eye. There's no such rules. No rules against partial answers. No rules against posting links to online learning resources. Despite your 3 claims of rules break neither fit the bill. Partial answers are allowed and encouraged and you're trying to argue it's against the rules when it isn't. It is ABSOLUTELY a place for teaching the basics because we all have to start some somewhere. You seem to have your own zealous textbook rules for how the site **should** run where a helpful, partial answer is somehow against your code.

Comment: Also, can I just say point out, you've strawmanned me in every single one of your comments so far and my patience wears thin. As i've stated, multiple times, this is a discussion around partial answers. Not the quality of the question or the experience of the author. It's not even relevant yet you keep going off-topic to insult non-existant authors. I stated that the answer presented would answer their question partially, as it's two pronged and they have an error and don't know how to identify it. The answer identifies it for them. Hence, partial answer. Hence, allowed under the site rules.

Comment: @Ryan Further, the kind of questions that would attract the tutorial-type answers you so want to be allowable, are the kind of questions that don't belong on this site. So your "solution" of posting tutorial answers to those questions is... not a solution because said questions shouldn't be answered anyway. In other words, your entire argument is predicated on nonsense, you know it, and since you have no counterargument you've resorted to accusations of bad faith... which you're making in bad faith. Hypocrisy much?

Comment: Ian, It may be legit outrage over faulty reasons. I 1/4 agree with Ryan. An answer that's "Use a debugger" is crap. Decent comment a lot of the time, though, if backed with a quick rundown on how to use a debugger. Part answers, assuming they're not misleading, just don't get upvotes from me unless they are pointing out something very important. I vehemently disagree with Stack Overflow as a place for teaching the basics. Where you draw the line on basics may vary, though.

Comment: If the asker cannot explain their problem or I can't explain the solution to the asker because they do not know enough of the terminology, they can't be helped without a study of the fundamentals. But, A) the fundamentals scale with the question, and B) Screw the asker. The answer might still be extremely useful to future askers who do have sufficient background understanding.