# How to handle questions about fundamental language knowledge

Tags: discussion, questions

Note, this is not the same as

- [Reviewing some awful questions is just a waste of time, can we have a "no comment" close reason for these?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261858/reviewing-some-awful-questions-is-just-a-waste-of-time-can-we-have-a-no-commen)
- [Can we please have the "Lacks Minimal Understanding" close reason back?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/257868/can-we-please-have-the-lacks-minimal-understanding-close-reason-back)

I don't ask for a close reason, I asked the question in order to get feedback from the community about the validity of such questions, as for me it's not yet clear if these are on-topic or off-topic questions.

---

For reference, see this question: [In the Swift programming language, what does "slider:UISlider" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28883846/in-swift-programming-language-what-means-slideruislider).

For someone who knows Swift it's clear what the `name: Type` syntax means, however the OP doesn't seem to know this.

How should this kind of questions be handled?

None of the standard close reasons seem to apply here:

- the question is not a duplicate
- it doesn't belong to other SE site
- it doesn't ask for libraries and tools
- it's not seeking debugging details
- it's not unclear
- it doesn't ask multiple questions in one
- it's not opinion based

The "Other" close reason can be applied here with a text like "I’m voting to close this question because it asks for mandatory language knowledge", though I'm not sure this kind of close reason is justified, as it's subjective.

Or are this kind of questions on-topic on SO?

Comment: It's not asking for a library or tool but it seems to me it is asking for an **off-site resource**, i.e. basic knowledge/tutorial. "We're not here to teach, we're here to help" as someone said a long time ago.

Comment: @Paulie_D It's not asking for an off-site resource (links to tutorials etc.). It's also not necessary to write a whole tutorial to answer it (too broad or more focus/details or clarity).

Comment: It's a simple and poor question. I don't think we have a close reason for those. We have votes at most. Maybe it's a duplicate? Is there no question dealing with swift basic syntax?

Comment: @yivi I don't think there is a question handling the basic Swift syntax, basically we'd need 100+ questions to handle all basic aspects of the language.

Comment: Related: [Do we need a close reason for zero-effort questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260828/11682469)

Comment: We need a close reason for personal motivation problems. Because not wanting to properly inform yourself and thus making your life far harder than it needs to be is not a programming problem, it's a personal one.

Comment: If there's no duplicate, answer it. Then, the next time someone asks it, close it as a dupe to that question.

Comment: @HereticMonkey do you propose to have a canonical question for every aspect of the language syntax?

Comment: @Cristik Given that Stack Overflow is a "_library of detailed answers to every question about programming_", why not? For JavaScript we have [What does this symbol mean in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9549780/what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-javascript) where all syntax/symbol related topics are bundled so they are easy to find when you want to close one as a duplicate.

Comment: @Cristik No. Just one for for every aspect that people have asked about. If no one ever asks "What does if mean in JavaScript?" I'll be happy.

Comment: @Ivar interesting, however the question linked here asks for even more basic stuff, so we'd need a question that would cover the whole Swift language guide, and that's a book with over 900 pages :)

Comment: Is the question useful? upvote it. Is it not useful? downvote it.

Comment: In Ancient Times, there was a "Lacks Minimal Understanding" close reason, but it was removed. I guess it wasn't very friendly...

Comment: Related (seems to be the same from the title... but I can't tell if the other question is that basic, because I don't know MVC) [How to deal with questions that ask about complete basics? - Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274645/how-to-deal-with-questions-that-ask-about-complete-basics)

Comment: The truly annoying thing about a question like this is odds are high that you won't be able to give the asker an answer they'll understand without reading the text book they should have read in the first place.

Comment: @user4581301 You wouldn't write the answer for the asker only  but also for any future visitor, so there may be something about it. But then, writing an answer linking to some official documentation is kind of boring. I just tend to run away from such simple questions that Google would have solved if only someone would have used it.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no "gormless" close category. — There used to be a close category "not a real question". So what I used to do is downvote and vote to close as "not a real question", the idea being that "not a real question" means "you have _got_ to be kidding". What I do now is downvote and vote to close as "unclear". What's "unclear" is how anyone willing to apply a modicum of effort could possibly not know this. I also add a comment consisting of a link to the relevant page of the online documentation. Then I walk away; there is absolutely no point commenting further.

Comment: @Trilarion [pretty much what I said yesterday](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/411765/should-me-too-posts-with-additional-research-details-be-considered-partial-ans/411767#comment870098_411767) If I think it'll help future asker, I'll answer. But I type slow and will almost certainly be scooped if the answer really is trivial.

Comment: I guess these types of questions you get, if people do not research their problems. Many people do, but some seem not to. Unfortunately these questions aren't really very valuable. I'd even go so far as to say that dealing with them wastes more time and effort than what they could bring in the end (another link to documentation somewhere). For me, the solution is basically only to stop participating because there is no easy to way to separate those questions from interesting ones. It's a pity for the interesting ones, but I cannot find them.

Comment: @PM2Ring "...I guess it wasn't very friendly... " The official reason given at the time was that it can easily be abused and I agree. Minimal understanding is kind of subjective. But then downvoting is nearly as effective as closing in setting a signal. The real problem is that any such question very likely is a duplicate but finding and marking as duplicates is work and takes time. You end up with a negative benefit.

Comment: Perhaps the title would be better phrased as "fundamental" rather than "mandatory" knowledge?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reviewing some awful questions is just a waste of time, can we have a "no comment" close reason for these?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261858/reviewing-some-awful-questions-is-just-a-waste-of-time-can-we-have-a-no-commen)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can we please have the "Lacks Minimal Understanding" close reason back?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/257868/can-we-please-have-the-lacks-minimal-understanding-close-reason-back)

Comment: @snakecharmerb yes, "fundamental" sounds much better than "mandatory", my only concern is that this might be a relative term, some people might find some language topics more fundamental than others.

Comment: @Cristik True, but the same applies to mandatory, and mandatory implies someone is mandating knowledge?  "Basic" might be another alternative.

Answer (score 33):

These questions are on-topic. They are asking about a programming problem. As you said, none of the close reasons apply. What you should do in this case is write an answer, but...

Easy questions like this one have usually been asked many times already. There's no reason to answer it again. Just look for the appropriate duplicate target and vote to close as a duplicate. If after a short search you can't find one, only then write a new answer.

Comment: Sounds good but, in effect, you are acting as a dupe lookup-drone for OP's who can't be bothered if they can con some mark into doing their work:(

Comment: @MartinJames Yes, that is what we all do on Stack Overflow. It's not easy to come up with an original question. These are rather rare. Majority can probably be closed as duplicates.

Comment: 'Yes, that is what we all do on Stack Overflow'....not all.  If I don't know the answer, I won't look it up.   If it's a trivial answer, I just comment some quick clue/tip.

Comment: @MartinJames: I usually look for a duplicate, but if I don't find one and the question is still trivial, yeah I just comment.  And either way downvote if it's too trivial, especially when searching on terms already used in the question should have pointed to an answer.  Or if it's one of the things any tutorial would cover.  Asking other humans is an exception; don't waste their time with things that everyone needs to learn when learning a new language, and thus is covered in tutorials.

Comment: @MartinJames Usually if I don't know the answer, but is familiar enough with the topic (to judge whether an answer is correct) I'd still look for a duplicate. /// I don't want to be a lookup-drone either, but the other option is doing nothing and someone else will answer it (...?) Downvote  remains an option.

Comment: Except that Stack Overflow's search function is garbage, which makes finding duplicates difficult if not impossible. Proper search engines get it right more of the time, but not always. So once again we are disincentivised from performing proper curation.

Comment: @IanKemp can find most duplicates in seconds with a `site:stackoverflow.com` search in Google.

Comment: "They are asking about a programming problem" I don't see a problem described in the mentioned question.

Comment: "...none of the close reasons apply." "Just look for the appropriate duplicate target and vote to close as a duplicate." Someone needs to revisit their formal logic, particularly the notion of contradiction.

Comment: There's absolutely no reward for finding duplicates (except when in a close-vote review queue). How would people be sustainably motivated?

Comment: @iBug "How would people be sustainably motivated?" They wouldn't. I guess the only "sustainable" way would be to constantly find new people willing to do this.

Comment: @Juraj The problem is they don't understand the thing they're asking about.

Answer (score -4):

For such questions, I have downvoted because the question lacks research and voted to close

> Community specific reason > Seeking recommendations for **books**, tools, software libraries, and more

<sub>(emphasis mine)</sub>

The [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) even says

> Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, **tutorial** or **other off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow

<sub>(emphasis mine)</sub>

Stack Overflow still is

> [...] for professional and enthusiast programmers, people who write code because they love it.

And really, they should have the basic language knowledge, and a book, tutorial or Youtube video should help getting started.

Comment: They aren't asking where to find resources though, so this is definitely the wrong close reason. "Simply typo" can be used from time to time. Most of these questions are just "down vote and move on" though.

Comment: Arguably, one could also type a custom close vote reason "I'm voting to close this because SO is not an interactive beginner tutorial", though that would be quite controversial and cause a lot of drama.

Comment: @Lundin: even if they don't know that they are looking for a tutorial, they are still looking for a tutorial. We have taught pupils Python in 3 afternoons and currently teach pupils Dart in the same time. They cover a lot of ground during that time. And we teach them not to ask such questions on SO ;-)

Comment: Teaching and learning isn't new to mankind. Schools and pedagogy have been around for some 2000 years. I can't picture someone in say the middle-ages go ask on the town square: "hey everyone I just started a smithy, but I have no idea what this hammer thing is supposed to do. Help please?" No, they would apprentice under an established smith and learn the trade from them. Mankind got dumber than ever thanks to the Internet, I guess...

Answer (score -10):

I usually leave a comment with an explanantion, and vote to close these questions as:

> **Not reproducible or was caused by a typo**

The logic seems simple to me: a typo is caused by a lack of attention to detail. It could have been resolved by a careful reading of the code and/or the documentation.

And simple questions like "what does X mean?", when a basic understanding of the language in question (and its documentation) would obviate the need for an answer, comes down to the same thing. The questioner simply wouldn't have asked in the first place had they paid attention to the things that they needed to.

Note that the blurb under this close reason says

> While similar questions **may be on-topic** here, this one was resolved in a way less likely to help future readers.

So even though the question *is on-topic*, it is not likely to help future readers, and therefore should be closed and deleted.

However, if it is likely that future readers, *including beginners*, may find it useful *after* having read the documentation, then it should not be closed. Try to put yourself in the place of a beginner, and imagine what they are able to understand.

Comment: It's often difficult to un-understand something. Especially when it's become obvious. I tend to read a lot of tutorials and every one of them lacks something for me. I assume the writer just found it obvious. Some little thing that makes it harder for me to keep reading. So I end up searching for it.. and then it's really nice to find a post that explains it.

Comment: True, I guess we need to make ourselves feel like beginners, read the documentation, then see if we still have a question

Comment: @Scratte it's the tutorial effect. People writing tutorials tend to do so assuming that everything in the world is perfect, everyone's job is as simple as "create a rest endpoint to insert a record into a database" and nothing can go wrong and nothing can be misunderstood. So why even bother covering fault scenario's, or highlighting common errors you might encounter? Except that this is usually exactly what people are looking for... robustness, not a happy flow implementation.